# App freezing when clicked on done button after selecting row from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have view consisting of `UIPickerView` and `Done button` and it is assigned as inputView to `textField`. After selecting any row from picker view and clicking `Done` app is un-expectingly `freezing`. I have attached stack trace screen shot at the time freeze. Please let know if this due something weird thread action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show your code. and at which line its crashing. show you console log after crash.

Comment: App is freezing not crashing...Its simple done action to button. After 6-7 sec everything works fine.

Comment: Add the code of Done button click action. You are doing some operation, which is blocking main thread

Comment: I am not performing any code done action. Simply returning from first line. Still app freezes.

Comment: Is there any API call on Done button?

Comment: No API call on done action.

Comment: show whatever code you're using, you have to mention the code first.

Comment: why if(currentTF.tag ==11) after return statement

Comment: See I have some action logic written there. But for my app is freezing though I am returning from 1st line without executing any of my code.

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace with an exception breakpoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this issue resolved. I had below code in my `- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification` notification method which was causing app to freeze.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardAnimationDuration.floatValue animations:^{

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    }];
```

App freeze issue is resolved after removing `[UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardAnimationDuration.floatValue animations:^{}];`

Finally, below code worked and now app is not freezing anymore.

```
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//here everything you want to perform in background

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    //call back to main queue to update user interface
});
});
```

I think this is help for you:
See this url of stack over flow

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426899/my-ios-app-freezes-but-no-error-appears)